# Swallows bring spring

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I recently read one article named as I mentioned above. That article is about birds and scientists are using them as means of measuring the climate change and impacts that it engenders.

I didn't understand why this article is named like this because there is nothing about 'spring' here.

Can you explain, please?

Comment: If the article is on line, please include a link to it. Swallows are migratory songbirds that arrive in northern regions in spring, when the weather turns warm, so their arrival is a sign of spring. Climate change affects temperatures of the seasons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Probably a mistaken attempt to refer to the proverb "one swallow does not a summer make".

Comment: Actually this article is from the magazine called "research*eu" . I am reading this in order to increase my reading ability. I had a difficulty to understand this article. This article is from publication No.62 - February 2010. page: 38.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swallows are migratory birds.  They appear in the Northern hemisphere in spring and their appearance marks the start of warmer weather.

So one might say that "swallows bring spring".  If you are interested in measuring the change to warmer weather, you might be interested in knowing the date when swallows start migrating in the (Northern hemisphere) Spring.